# Umbraco Only display child node if the DocumentTypeAlias is equal to

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7. I have a parent node with 2 different types of child nodes.

About

--Bio 1 (Child node type 1)

--Bio 2 (Child node type 1)

--FAQ 1 (Child node type 2)

--FAQ 2 (Child node type 2)

What I want to do is only display one type of child node *ie* if the child node document type is == to "fAQ" show FAQ

```
    @{ var selection = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible") && Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias == "fAQ";  }
    @{ var i = 1; }
    @foreach (var item in selection)
    {
  <p>Hello I am an FAQ child node</p>
        i+=1;
    }
```

My problem is coming from the Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias == "fAQ"; i think...

I cant figure this one out for the life of me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: var selection = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible").Where(c => c.DocumentTypeAlias  == "fAQ");

Maybe something like this ? I didn't get your question

Comment: Hi @AlexKvitchastiy That seemed didn't seem to work. 

To simplify the question: How do you only show a child node if the DocumentTypeAlias has a certain name?

Comment: What does your modelsbuilder say? PureLive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```
var children = new List<IPublishedContent>();
if (Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias == "fAQ") { 
   children = Model.Content.Children().Where(i => i.IsVisible());
}
```

If you want to only display child nodes of type "fAQ", you can do the following:

```
var children = Model.Content.Children().Where(i => i.DocumentTypeAlias == "fAQ" && i.IsVisible());
```